# Rules for App Store video app preview

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

For service apps, much like Uber, can the demonstration video be of a real life example showing how the service works and also the application itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the full Apple Review Guideline
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

And it says in 3.14 that "App previews may only use video screen captures of the app, voice-overs, and textual and design overlays, or the app will be rejected"

Hope this helps

Comment: does this mean we cannot have a device frame in it?